# Why we use Class.forName(“oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver”) while connecting to a database?

Tags: java, jdbc

What is the actual use of `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")` while connecting to a database? Why cant we just import the same class, instead why we are loading it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose 'Class.forName("MY\_JDBC\_DRIVER")'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662902/what-is-the-purpose-class-fornamemy-jdbc-driver)

Answer (score 31):

The basic idea behind using `Class.forName()` is to load a JDBC driver implementation. A (normal) JDBC driver must contain a static initializer that registers an instance of the driver implementation with `java.sql.DriverManager`:

> JDBC drivers must implement the `Driver` interface, and the implementation must contain a static initializer that will be called when the driver is loaded. This initializer registers a new instance of itself with the `DriverManager`

(from JDBC 4.1, section 9.2)

Since JDBC 4.0 however there is a new way to register drivers: the jar of a JDBC driver needs to include a file `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` which contains the name(s) of the `java.sql.Driver` implementations in that jar. When you create a connection using the `DriverManager`, it will use `java.util.ServiceLoader` to enumerate all `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` files in the classpath and load all drivers so they get registered.

> The `DriverManager.getConnection` method has been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file  `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. This file contains the name of the JDBC driver’s implementation of `java.sql.Driver`.

(from JDBC 4.1, section 9.2.1)

The reasons drivers are loaded this way, is that it allows you to decouple an application from the driver (and database) it uses. This means that you can write, compile and even distribute an application without any drivers, you only need to use the interfaces provided in the `java.sql` (and `javax.sql`) package - which is part of Java - without needing to access the implementation directly.

The user of the application then adds a valid JDBC driver to the classpath (and configuring things like a connection string) so the application can actually to connect to a database. Before JDBC 4.0, the user would have to specify the driver name so that the application could load it using `Class.forName`, with a JDBC 4.0 compliant driver and Java 6 or higher this discovery is automatic.

When you load a driver literally with `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")` it might feel like overkill, but if you keep in mind that it could also be a string pulled from a config file (or from user input) you might start to understand why it is so powerful.

Of course this driver independence is not 100%, especially not if your application uses vendor specific SQL. But the theory is that your application can be database independent. JDBC also provides some additional mechanisms to address this, eg JDBC escapes to provide a common syntax that the driver translates to the specific syntax, and `DatabaseMetaData` which allows you to discover features, reserved words etc which allow you to create or generate compatible queries.

Comment: In a world where JDBC publishers would like to license their drivers and disallow packaging their driver with software, I can see how this pattern would be useful.

Comment: It is also useful when the FQN for the driver class changes ... as has happened **at least twice** for MySQL database drivers.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, or consider MariaDB which - IIRC - initially did not have JDBC driver, so you could use the MySQL driver, and now you can use the MariaDB driver instead. There are also some commercial parties that offer alternative drivers, and consider jTDS vs SQL Server JDBC, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It`s a legacy way to do so. Importing class you will have extra dependency

From The Java Tutorial:

> In previous versions of JDBC, to obtain a connection, you first had to
> initialize your JDBC driver by calling the method Class.forName. This
> methods required an object of type java.sql.Driver. Each JDBC driver
> contains one or more classes that implements the interface
> java.sql.Driver.
>
> ...
>
> Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class
> path are automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any
> drivers prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)

Answer (score 5):

A couple reasons to use `Class.forName("")` instead of just referencing the class directly:

1. Using `Class.forName("")` gives you more obvious control over where exactly the first attempt to load the specified class will be made in your code.  This makes it more obvious where the code will fail (throw an exception) if that class is not present in the classpath when that code runs.
2. If you simply import the class and then reference it in your code, it becomes slightly less obvious where the code will throw an exception if the class is not present.
3. Also, using `Class.forName("")` is a way to get around potential compile-time restrictions.  If, for example, the person compiling the code does not (for, let's say, licensing or intellectual property reasons) have access to the class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, they may find it easier to compile code which references the class by `Class.forName("")` rather than directly.
4. If you do not need to use any methods, fields, or inner classes of the specified class, then `Class.forName("")` may be the clearest way to express that the only thing desired is to load the class (and have its static initializers run), and nothing else.

I don't think Class.forName exhibits any different functional behavior than referencing the class directly.  It uses the calling class' classloader by default, which should be the same classloader that is used when referencing the class directly.  There are some overloads to Class.forName("") that let you customize the class loading behavior a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is required to load a class during the run time. i.e, any class can be loaded into the memory location dynamically while executing the java application. The `Class.forName` is used to load any given class (within double quotes as String) at run time. For example, when we use IDE, we see there will be a GUI builder which allows us to drag and drop the buttons, text fields, etc. This drag and drop mechanism internally requires certain classes to be loaded at run time.

In the Class.forName (`sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`), the Class belongs to the package `java.lang.Class` and the `forName()` is a static method of the `java.lang.Class`. The JDBC Drivers (String) will be loaded into the class dynamically at run time and forName method contains static block which creates the Driver class object and register with the `DriverManager` Service automatically. Since the `forName()` is static, we call it using the class name (Class).

Answer (score -1):

When we want to execute static block of a class, without creating its object then we can use `class.forName()`. Most of the work that `Driver` class do, exists in its static block.

Now what we require in our JDBC connectivity is to get the  driver registered with `DriverManager` and to obtain connections with it, so this can be achieved simply by getting static block executed and there is no requirement to create object of that class. This approach will give a better performance.

Comment: 'Better performance' than what? It is no different from what presently happens by default as long as the driver complies with JDBC 4.