# Try with resources Statement for JDBC in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Useful piece of code for Hive JDBC:

```
       Connection con = null;
       Statement stmt = null

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUri, userName, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cex) {
            cex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to remove try - catch in **finally** block.

So I tried [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
        try (Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUri, userName, password);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();){

            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cex) {
            cex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I think this is not the right way.

`Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")` should not be in try. Should I make a separate try-catch for this?

```
       try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cex) {
            cex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUri, userName, password);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();){

            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is this right way or am I missing any thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea behind try-with-ressource is to close an `AutoCloseable` class.
So every usage of a class which should be closed after using it (a Ressource) can be used with try-with-ressource (like Connection for example). You don't have to take care of closing it manually (in an finally block for example).

So yes, your idea is right:

- try/catch for `Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");` - because this is not AutoCloseable
- try-with-ressource for `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUri, userName, password);
          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();`- because `Connection` and `Statement` implement AutoCloseable

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

Answer (score 2):

When you're using Java 6 or better and the Apache Hive JDBC driver is JDBC 4 compliant or better* then you do not need the `Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")` stuff at all.

Therefore you can just remove the entire try/catch block from your second solution and you're good to go with just:

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUri, userName, password);
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {

    stmt.executeUpdate(query);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

* Which is the case for version 1.2.0 or newer of the Hive JDBC driver

Comment: Why is this? Shouldn't Java still have to instantiate the driver? I am using the jtds driver and am noticing the same thing, when I forget to instantiate it, the program still runs normally.

Comment: @jabeoogie, this is answered at [Why we use Class.forName(“oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver”) while connecting to a DataBase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078586/why-we-use-class-forname-oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while-connecting-to)