# Apache Flink - External Jar

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, apache-flink, flink-streaming

i'm trying to create a Flink application using maven and an extra dependency :

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>8.2.2.jre11</version>
  </dependency>
```

Im trying to fetch extra information from our database. When I run the code locally, everything is fine, but when run on Flink, I get this error message : 
[image]

So my initial tought was the dependency was not loaded on the fat jar using the maven shadow pluging, but I think it is. 
[image]

My Flink is run in a docker container, Ive open port 1433:1433 on the container (in the compose).

My goal is to add SQL data to the stream for an alerting system with custom rules by user.

Here is the content of my pom.xml :

-->
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.qscale</groupId>
<artifactId>FlinkPrototype</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>
<url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <flink.version>1.10.0</flink.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
    <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->

    <!-- Example:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- Project dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.2.jre11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
    <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Java Compiler -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
        <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>org.qscale.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving some warnings. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>shade</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: mask the db string in the image and also the credentials. it is considered sensitive information.

Comment: Just a trivial check. Have you added `Class.forName` clause?

Comment: @chuckskull for the dependency ? For the project I have,<mainClass>org.qscale.StreamingJob</mainClass>
in the shade plugin->transformers section

Comment: Adding this in your `main` method might work for you I think because shading seems correct., `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")`
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080771/8084588 for more details.

Comment: @chuckskull Haa I think Ive found the problem. I have this error when run with your suggestion :

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

The java version in the container is OpenJdk8. I guess this is the issue and probably also the cause for why it was not working earlier.

Comment: Adding it as an answer.

Comment: Glad you found your solution. At least on our end we recommend still using Java 8. We have seen some strange errors with scala and java > 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` in your main method will work for you I think because shading seems correct.

The other problem is that you are using java 1.8 to compile in your pom but you are adding a dependency compiled with java 11. Changing the jdbc version to the following will hopefully work.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>8.2.2.jre8</version>
  </dependency>
```

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080771/8084588) for more details

Answer (score 0):

How are you running it on flink? In IDE? Docker? EC2
You might need to add the dependency to your classpath.

You can also try changing the scope dependency to compile in your pom.

compile

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So it is run in docker. By default, if the scope is not specify, it is set to compile.
How do I add my dependancy to classpath?