# JDBC Driver Types 3 and 1

Tags: jdbc, odbc, driver

I am new to Java and i´m writing an assesy for school about database connections via JDBC. 
Am i getting this right about the driver type 3:

> The JDBC Type 3 driver is an all java driver witch calls JDBC Functions and sends them to a middle tier server, where they are transformed in vendor specific native database calls or to ODBC calls, which are then handled by an ODBC driver and sent to the database.

I also read that its possible to transform them to ODBC calls. I assume that this means a JDBC-ODBC-Bridge is used. If that is so, how is it possible to do that, because i read that ODBC drivers need to be installed on the Client and cant be loaded over the network(according to descriptions of driver type 1).
And furthermore, why on earth would anybody use a type 1 driver on Clientside, where you need to install native code and the ODBC driver on the Client machine?

Am I getting something wrong here or is the type 1 driver just an ancient technology which can be found in descriptions of JDBC but noone uses anymore.

Please help me getting the right idea.

Comment: It should be noted that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8 so it is definitely a legacy technology.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/jdbc-driver-types.htm has a good overview of the various JDBC driver types. As you suspected, the type 1 drivers are generally considered a legacy option nowadays.

You can find a good stack overflow reference on the same topic at [What is type 1,2,3 or 4 of a JDBC Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658727/what-is-type-1-2-3-or-4-of-a-jdbc-driver)