# What is meant by vendor database library in jdbc concept?

Tags: jdbc

I am learning about JDBC. When I am learning about it, I have come to known we can use 4 drivers. In each of these architecture I find the vendor database libraries in jdbc-odbc bridge driver and also native API calls in other type 3, 4.

I am unable to know about those concepts in the architecture.

So I request anyone to say about those two concepts which deals with the JDBC drivers.

I have referred the below link :
http://www.javatpoint.com/jdbc-driver

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658727/what-is-type-1-2-3-or-4-of-a-jdbc-driver/17658875

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is type 1,2,3 or 4 of a JDBC Driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658727/what-is-type-1-2-3-or-4-of-a-jdbc-driver)

Comment: BTW: Your question is still very unclear and tries to ask about at least four different things. The vendor of the JDBC driver, the vendor of the ODBC driver, the vendor of the database system, JDBC driver types, and what native libraries have to do with anything...

Comment: But simply put: the vendor is the organization (company, non-profit, individual) that holds the copyright on the piece of software you use.

Answer (score 2):

Vendor based database libraries means you need to use libraries provided by vendors to connect to database.
For example
You need to use ojdbc6.jar for Oracle , postgresql-9.4.1207.jar for postgresql etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** database is called a vendor database if you interact with it through JDBC using special drivers.

JDBC is an API, which allows you to work with different databases (such as MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.) using the same methods to query and update data in a database. This happens by using special drivers, which are unique for every database. In this case the database you are working with is called a vendor database.